# Google plus comment not showing up after clicked current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

Google plus comment not showing up after clicked current tab (using Organic Tabs).

You can check this : http://youtubethumb.blogspot.com/2013/06/thoi-hoc-sinh-ban-tung.html

```
<li class='nav-one'><a class='current' href='#featured'>Facebook comment</a></li>
                <li class='nav-two'><a href='#core'>Google+ comments</a></li>
                <li class='nav-three'><a href='#hard'>Record</a></li>
            </ul>
<div class='list-wrap'>

                <div id='featured'>
                  <fb:comments data-id='1' data-title='Góc nghĩ' expr:href='data:post.url' height='160' style='margin:10px 0px 0px 5px' width='700'/>
                </div>

                 <div class='hide' id='core'>
                   <div style="min-height:200px; display:block; position:relative">
 <script src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js'/>
<div id='comments'/>
<script>
gapi.comments.render(&quot;comments&quot;, {
href: window.location,
width: &quot;700&quot;,
first_party_property: &quot;BLOGGER&quot;,
view_type: &quot;FILTERED_POSTMOD&quot;
});
</script> 
                   </div>
                 </div>
```

I do it with blogger. Can everyone helps me to solve this?

Here is organic tabs:   http://jsfiddle.net/happi/ZDY6v/

Comment: There are two error on the blogger :  
document.getElementbyId is not a function
showSocial = document.getElementsById("show-social"); line 1114
and 
TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function
line 1013

Comment: This does not affect to Google+ comment. It shows sometimes also.

Comment: In the Jsfiddle there s a error JSON.parse: unexpected character in the file plutone.js!